# How to automatically synchronize tables in different databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Little background: I'm working in a large company with a lot of branches. We have several applications with separated databases sometimes on different servers. But every database contains a table with a list of branches and their relationships. I want to automatically synchronize these tables when one of them changed.

**My question is: what are the best practices of automatic synchronization of tables in different databases (Microsoft SQL Server 2008)?**

Are there sql server features for that purpose? Or external tool is a good way? Or it's better to write a small application and run it as a service or use the scheduler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use replication (a SQL server built-in feature) to synchronize different databases.
You can also use triggers or log shipping to sync your tables as records are added ,updated or deleted:

[Here](http://www.google.com/search?q=SQL+Server+2008+replication) are some links about replication.

[Here](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=SQL+Server+2008+Log+Shipping) are some links about log shipping.